# Flutter: close scanner after scan success

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I use **flutter_barcode_scanner** to scan the barcode or QR code, but after scan success, I do not know the way how to close that scan screen, please help.

Thanks,

Sourn visal

Comment: show your code first.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_barcode_scanner

Comment: Hi, you can't close it. but what you can do is add a controller,
for example String barcodeResult;
in your widget do something like barcodeResult == null ? showBarcode() : showSomethingElse().

barcodeResult is your controller.

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly showing in demo using async and future.

```
Future<void> scanQR() async {
    String barcodeScanRes;
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          "#ff6666", "Cancel", true, ScanMode.QR);
      print(barcodeScanRes);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Failed to get platform version.';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is way I have use to stop QR scanner after successful scanning

```
  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
   this.controller = controller;
    controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
      controller.pauseCamera(); //====> pause camera once scan is done
      setState(() {
        result = scanData;            
        print(scanData.code);     
        //Navigate other page if you want
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => const ScannedResult(),
          ),
        );
      });
     });
   }
```